# how can i get an empty gameobject and replace its sprite with a random card sprite?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make blackjack in unity and the first thing im going to start out with is trying to have an assortment of empty gameobjects on the screen and when i click a button they will take a random card sprite from the folder of 52 prefabs i made, and make that gameobjects sprite be the card. it would be really inefficient to load each sprite into each gameobject individually, so is there a way i can pull it from the folder by itself?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class cardstuff : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        spriteRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }
    public SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    public Sprite currentCards;
    
    public void ChangeSprite()
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = currentCards;
        Debug.Log("changeSprite Initiated");
    }



    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            ChangeSprite();
        }
    }










}
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAll.html ?

Comment: I think so! Thank you. I wish i could mark a comment as answer lol

Comment: I will add it as the answer then.

Comment: That answer doesn't at all fit/answer your question title though.. try to modify it to something more descriptive

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could follow the docs [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAll.html) and do something like this:

```
public class cardstuff : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Object[] deckOfCards;
    public SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    public Sprite currentCard;

    void Awake() {
        // load all sprites from "Resources/Sprites/"
        deckOfCards = Resources.LoadAll("Sprites", typeof(Sprite));
        spriteRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }
    
    public void ChangeSprite() {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = deckOfCards[Random.Range(0, deckOfCards.Length)];
        Debug.Log("card sprite changed");
    }

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            ChangeSprite();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for the hint @Rich, i improved the answer.

Comment: [Note that in general you shouldn't use `Resources` at all!](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a6) especially if OP is concerned about efficiency and memory usage ^^

Comment: Also this ca barely be an in-between step.. later you for sure want to avoid picking the same card twice ;) also @OP only having the sprite itself is worth nothing.. you actually also need to associate them with certain card values in order to properly deal with them

Comment: @derHugo i cant say anything against your comments cuz they are right but i believe OP is far from a position where section `3.2. Proper uses of the Resources system` of your link does not apply.

Comment: @taiyo Thank you so much the previous link put me in a dead end because i was too stupid to understand it, the code you provided was great except for a minor change i had to make to make an error go away, Thank you again!